# C# Write Async a specific data size

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, buffer

I have an API in C# that returns data from a DB and a frontend that paints that data in a table.

My approach was to read the data from the DB with an sqlReader, iterate through this reader adding each result to a list and return that list to the frontend.

Seems easy enough, until I receive massive query data. My solution was to return this data chunk by chunk but I'm stuck with it, this is the code I'm working with:

```
 var sqlCommand = db.InitializeSqlCommand(query);
                try
                {
                    using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var results = new List<List<string>>();
                        var headers = new List<string>();
                        var rows = new List<string>();
                        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            headers.Add(reader.GetName(i));
                        }
                        results.Add(headers);
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                rows.Add((reader[reader.GetName(i)]).ToString());
                            }
                            results.Add(rows);
                            var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
                            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            rows.Clear();
                            results.Clear();
                            outputStream.Flush();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147023667) // The remote host closed the connection. 
                    {
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    outputStream.Close();
                    db.Dispose();
                }
```

With this, I'm able to return data one by one (tested with the Thread.sleep), but I'm stuck on how to return a specific amount, say 200 data or 1000, it really should not matter.

Any idea on how to proceed?
Thanks in advance.
Mese.

Comment: How about using `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` in your SQL command? You can increase the `OFFSET` for every subsequent run. Example - after ORDER BY clause add 'OFFSET 200 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY` to skip 200 rows and get the next 200

Comment: That is not a possibility, it's a dynamic query, I'm not supposed to know what query is comming. That's why I want everything to be dynamic

Comment: So you don't have control over the query. Then the only way is by controlling how many rows the reader reads. How about `foreach(var row in reader.AsEnumerable.Skip(200).Take(200)) { // operation }` and you can modify the 200 in subsequent calls

Comment: But that would mean, go to the code, skip 200, get the results. Next query, go to the code, manually change the 200 for 400..and so one? Or am I understanding poorly the code?

Comment: that's correct `.Skip()` should be `.Skip(0)` the first time, then 200, then 400 and so on.

Comment: then I need a dynamic way to increase that amount. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you will, you can answer the question and I'll gladly accept it. I think I can write something using your guidance that will work.

Comment: Sure @Mese. I've added a basic outline of what you can try. Let me know if it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think controlling the query is the better way since that is what will be fetched from the database. You can increase the `OFFSET` for every subsequent run. Example - after `ORDER BY` clause add `OFFSET 200 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY` to skip 200 rows and get the next 200.

However since you've mentioned that you have no control on the query, then you can do something like this to filter our results on your end. The key trick here is to use `reader.AsEnumerable.Skip(200).Take(200)` to choose which rows to process. Update the input to `Skip()` in every iteration to process data accordingly.

```
// Offset variable will decide how many rows to skip, the outer while loop can be
// used to determine if more data is present and increment offset by 200 or any
// other value as required. Offset -> 0, 200, 400, 600, etc.. until data is present

bool hasMoreData = true;
int offset = 0;
while(hasMoreData)
{
    // SQL Data reader and other important operations
    foreach(var row in reader.AsEnumerable.Skip(offset).Take(200)) 
    { 
        // Processing operations
    }
    // Check to ensure there are more rows
    if(no more rows)
        hasMoreData = false;
    offset += 200;
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is when you pull the data in batches, the query will execute multiple times and if during that time, a new record got added or deleted, then the batches will not function correctly. To get past this, you can do 2 things:

- Validate a Unique ID of every record with unique ID's of already fetched records to make sure the same record isn't pulled twice (edge case due to record addition/deletion)
- Add a buffer to your offset, such as

  - `Skip(0).Take(100)` // Pulls 0 - 100 records
  - `Skip(90).Take(100)` // Pulls 90 - 190 records (overlap of 10 to cater for additions/deletions)
  - `Skip(180).Take(100)` // Pulls 180 - 280 records (overlap of 10 to cater for additions/deletions)
  - and so on...

Hope this helps!

Comment: For anyone interested, this code kinda works for me, the only difference is I need a dynamic way to increase the skip amount, so I just added a variable and increase its size each loop. Thanks @degant